# Querying a Sequelize model to match multiple associations

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js, model-associations

So I have two Sequelize models with this relationship:

```
models.Note.belongsToMany(models.Topic, {
 through: 'noteTopicRelation'
});

models.Topic.belongsToMany(models.Note, {
 through: 'noteTopicRelation'
});
```

I can make a successful query to the Note model like so, getting all the Notes that belong to the Topic with the id of 2:

```
models.Note.findAll({
 include: [{
   model: models.Topic,
   through: 'noteTopicRelation',
 }]
 where: {
  '$topics.id$': 2
 }
})
```

However, what if I only want a Note that has multiple specific Topics associated with it (i.e. a Note that is associated with Topics of ids 1, 4, 6)?

I have tried adding this operator on my where:

```
where: {
'$topics.id$': {$overlap: [1, 4, 6]}
}
```

But getting an error:

> operator does not exist: uuid && text[]

Am I using `Op.overlap` incorrectly? Is there another way to achieve this result? Thank you!

**EDIT:** and just to clarify (sorry if this wasn't clear in my original post), I want to get the notes that are strictly associated with *all* of those Topics. Performing a `'$topics.id$': [1, 4, 6]` will get me notes that are associated with *any* of those Topics.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `$in` rather than `$overlap`; the latter maps to the PostgreSQL `&&` operator which is meant for range types, not lists.

So I suggest trying:

```
where: {
  '$topics.id$': [1, 4, 6]
}
```

The above will get notes which have ANY of the topic IDs (posted before the question was edited to say that only notes with ALL of the provided `topic.id`s should be returned).

As per the link to the discussion on the Sequelize github issues page in the comments below; one way to get notes with ALL of the topic IDs, you'll need to do something like the following:

```
var topicIds = [1, 4, 6];
models.NoteTopicRelation
    .findAll({
        include: [
            {model: models.Topic, where: {id: topicIds}}
        ],
        group: ['note_id'],
        having: ['COUNT(*) >= ?', topicIds.length]
    })
    .then((noteTopicItems) => models.Note.find({
        where: {id: noteTopicItems.map((item) => item.note_id)}
    }))
    .then((notes) => {
        // do something with notes
    });
```

Note that this method only reliably works if the link table (ie `noteTopicRelation` in your case) has only unique pairs of `note_id` & `topic_id` - ie. there is a `unique` key of some sort on these fields. Otherwise a topic can be assigned to a note more than once, which will throw up the `COUNT(*)`. I believe the default "through" tables that Sequelize creates have a `unique` key on both fields; there are legitimate cases where this might not be desired however so I thought it worth mentioning.

Also note that I've made some assumptions about the column/property names of your `noteTopicRelation` model in the above query so you'll probably need to tweak them.

Another thing to note - the join from NoteTopicRelation to Topic isn't really necessary in the example case; you could achieve the same thing more efficiently using `where: {topic_id: topicIds}` (which would avoid the join to `Topic`) if you are only wanting to filter by `topic.id`. I've left the join there in case you're actually wanting to query on e.g. topic name or include other attributes from the `Topic` model/table in your `where` clause (e.g. an `enabled` attribute or similar).

Comment: I think you can simplify a little bit, like this: ```where: {
  '$topics.id$': [1, 4, 6]
}``` Sequelize automaticaly add `in`

Comment: Thanks, of course! I forgot that... I’ve edit the answer with your simplification.

Comment: Hey @Timshel, thanks for the post! Sorry if I wasn't clear in my original post, but I'm wanting to grab the Notes that are strictly associated with ALL of those topics. Performing the method you suggested gets me the Notes associated with ANY of them. My fault for not being clear though (still don't know if that's entirely clear). Updated my post!

Comment: Ok that’s a fair bit more difficult- the easiest way to achieve this from a SQL perspective is to inner join to the link table (ie noteTopicRelation) multiple times- once for each of your topic IDs. I don’t think this can be done using the basic Sequelize querying; you might be best to write a straight SQL query or stored proc to do the job

Comment: Have a read of [this fairly detailed discussion on Sequelize's github issues page](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1585) about how to achieve this. This solution uses a single join together with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(*) = [number of topics]` statements to get only notes with **ALL** topics (using your DB terminology).

Comment: It seems the easy way to do this with Sequelize is to perform 2 queries: 1: on the link table to find values of `note_id` with ALL topics, and 2: to get the actual notes using the `note_id` list, the better way is to do it in one query, but it's not clear from the issue discussion if this can be done without modifying Sequelize's sources.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a more specific example of how querying only notes which have ALL topic IDs might be achieved in your scenario.